# how to in set javascript id in input value

Tags: javascript

i want to inset my javascript id in to the place of input value .

if i give  `Interest` name input `value="100"`

how can i get  `tc` named table input `value="75"`

**my input form**

```
    <tr>
                            <th>Loan Amount</th>
                            <th>INTEREST RATE %</th>
    <tr>              
            <tbody>
<td><input disabled type="" name="tc" id="int_amount" class="formcontrol"value=""/></td>
<td><input  type="number" name="Interest" id="input2" onkeyup="calculate();"/ class="form-control" value=""/></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

**javascript**

```
var vatti = document.pricecal.Interest.value;
var Total = vatti -25;

    if(vatti = null)
    {

        document.getElementById("int_amount").innerHTML  = "Rs:"+" "+Total;

    }
[want out put like this][1]
```

Comment: What?!! Explain more please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```js
function calculate(interest){
  var vatti = interest.value;
  if (vatti != '') {
    var Total = vatti - 25;
      document.getElementById("int_amount").value = Total;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("int_amount").value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="number" name="Interest" id="input2" onkeyup="calculate(this)" onchange="calculate(this)" class="form-control" value=""/></td>
     <td><input type="" name="tc" id="int_amount" class="formcontrol" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.value` of the `<input>` element, not the `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("int_amount").value  = "Rs:"+" "+Total;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="Interest" id="input2" class="form-control" value=""/></td>
    <td><input type="" name="tc" id="int_amount" class="formcontrol" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('input2').onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('int_amount').value = (this.value != '') ? 'Rs: ' + (parseInt(this.value)-25) : '';
}
```